# Swift Get URLSessionDataTask start time / current operation time

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I have a `URLSessionDataTask` instance and I would like to know when the operation started (a `Date` object) so I can calculate how much time has elapsed.

I've found `URLSessionTaskTransactionMetrics` in Apple's documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontasktransactionmetrics#declarations) but this does not show how to get the `transactionMetrics` property, unless I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have already set your view controller as the `URLSessionTaskDelegate`, you just need to override url session [didFinishCollecting](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate/1643148-urlsession) metrics method, iterate over the metrics transactionMetrics and get its fetchStartDate:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didFinishCollecting metrics: URLSessionTaskMetrics) {
    for metric in metrics.transactionMetrics {    
        print(task.response?.url ?? "", metric.fetchStartDate?.description(with: .current) ?? "")
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to set the delegate of my URLSession to a delegate conforming object, e.g. URLSession.shared.delegate = Object<URLSessionDelegate>, but I'm getting a 'delegate' is a get-only property warning. Am I setting the right delegate? It doesn't seem that URLSessionTasks have a delegate property either.

Comment: I'm forever in your debt, Leo.